# How to tell helm not to deploy a resource or remove it if a value is set to "false"?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, helm, yaml

I am working on an HPA template that will be applied only if the `enabled` value is set to true. Currently when setting `enabled` to false, it will create an empty object in yaml. This is then applied with an error stating that there is no `apiVersion` defined. How can I tell helm to not apply the HPA template if the value is set to `false` our skip the resource templating?

values.yaml:

```
# hpa
hpa:
  enabled: false
  maxReplicas: 10
  minReplicas: 2
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 70
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 70
```

hpa.yaml:

```
{{- template "common.hpa" (list . "service.deployment") -}}
{{- define "service.deployment" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

_hpa.yaml:

```
{{- define "common.hpa.tpl" -}}
{{ if .Values.hpa.enabled }}
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: {{ required "serviceName value is required" $.Values.serviceName }}
  namespace: {{ required "namespace value is required" $.Values.namespace }}
spec:
  maxReplicas: {{ .Values.hpa.maxReplicas }}
  minReplicas: {{ .Values.hpa.minReplicas }}
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ required "serviceName value is required" $.Values.serviceName }}
  metrics:
{{ toYaml .Values.hpa.metrics | indent 4 }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "common.hpa" -}}
{{- include "common.util.merge" (append . "common.hpa.tpl") -}}
{{- end -}}
```

_util.yaml

```
{{- /*
common.util.merge will merge two YAML templates and output the result.
This takes an array of three values:
- the top context
- the template name of the overrides (destination)
- the template name of the base (source)
*/}}
{{- define "common.util.merge" -}}
{{- $top := first . -}}
{{- $overrides := fromYaml (include (index . 1) $top) | default (dict ) -}}
{{- $tpl := fromYaml (include (index . 2) $top) | default (dict ) -}}
{{- toYaml (merge $overrides $tpl) -}}
{{- end -}}
```

output from running `helm template`

```
---
# Source: service/templates/hpa.yaml
{}
```

error message when doing a `helm install`:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]
helm.go:84: [debug] error validating "": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've specified:

```
{{ if .Values.hpa }}
---
...
```

To skip that code when enabled is false, you'd need:

```
{{ if .Values.hpa.enabled }}
---
...
```

Comment: Sorry I need to update my question. It is currently set to `{{ if .Values.hpa.enabled }}`

Comment: It currently skips the code but the output is `{}`. It hen tries to apply that but it is invalid.